# AttributeError: partially initialized module 'folium' has no attribute 'Map' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, linux, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run this Map object but whenever i execute the script on terminal i am getting this error. But when i run this in a python shell, it works perfectly. I am using this code.

```
    import folium
    a = folium.Map(location=[27.788032, 85.380830], zoom_start=15, tiles="Stamen Terrain")
    a.save("Map1.html")
```

I am not understanding this error. I am using VS code and i am on ubuntu 20.04. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What is the full traceback? What version of python? What version of folium? Did you create a file named folium.py?

Comment: I would add: do you have the same error when running `python -c "import folium"` in an empty directory? It is very strange to have an all-out import error on a known library, I have mostly had that with the `__init__.py` of crudely-hacked packages written by yours truly

Answer (score 2):

ran into the same error message and was using a python file 'folium.py'.
If you used the same name. Try renaming it.